# wxWidgets and code:blocks - missing <wx/led.h> for LED component

Tags: c++, codeblocks, wxwidgets

when I design GUI with codeblocks, I got compiling error on this line:

```
Led1 = new  wxLed(Panel1,ID_LED1,wxColour(0,0,0),wxColour(0,255,0),
                  wxDefaultPosition,wxDefaultSize);
```

the error is showed [in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RR05b.png)

I followed the suggestion on this
[link page](http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=17797.0)
I downloaded the lead.h/cpp file from sourceforge
and added both files into my project folder, also include .h file, 
here is one piece of the code in the led.cpp file, it seems like it has the function I need to create the led object, but no idea why I still got compiler error:

```
#include "led.h"

#include <string.h>

BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE (wxLed, wxWindow)
    EVT_PAINT (wxLed::OnPaint)
END_EVENT_TABLE ()

wxLed::wxLed(wxWindow * parent, wxWindowID id, wxColour disableColour, wxColour onColour, wxColour offColour, const wxPoint & pos, const wxSize & size)
{
    Create(parent, id, disableColour, onColour, offColour, pos, size);
}

wxLed::wxLed ()
{

}


wxLed::~wxLed ()
{
    delete m_bitmap ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The complier is telling you: you are passing a `const wxPoint` instead of a `wxColour`.  
You need to pass three colours and you are passing only two.